# exec() error when using find -exec

Tags: c, find, exec

I've to find with a script an executable named *Test* that take as argument a path, and execute it. I'm doing this with this line:

```
find -name Test -exec {} path \;
```

In *Test* I got an execl:

```
    execl("./Test1","Test1",(char*)0);
    perror("Exec failed");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

where *Test1* is in the same directory of *Test* . Executing *Test*  "manually" everything goes fine, but using the line written above I have a  *Exec failed: No such file or directory* error.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Just curious; why would you want to execute the path?

Comment: firstly, does find actually find the file?

Comment: I'm a big newbie with these stuff, so I've probably done several banal error however in order to answer you: @rsplak : path is the argument of _Test_, as I read from the man page: _All following arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command  until  an  argument consisting of `;' is encountered._  is it wrong ?

Comment: What does your command look like if you `echo` it? Is it as expected? (i.e., change the exec to `-exec echo {} path \;`); this will print the command rather than execute it so you can validate it's what you expect.

Comment: Do you have permission to execute `Test`?

Comment: @ChrisJ yes, it's exactly what I expected

Comment: This sounds dangerous, by the way. Shouldn't you *know* where your executables live before running them? This will run *all* executables named `Test` found under the current directory tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

find executes `Test` from the directory you are executing `find`. If you can change the code for Test, then put the absolute path of Test1:

```
execl("/home/myuser/some/path/Test1","Test1",(char*)0);
perror("Exec failed");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Or you can use `-execdir` instead of `-exec`:

```
find -name Test -execdir {} path \;
```

From find manpage:

> **-execdir**: Like -exec, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory 
>   containing  the matched  file, which is not normally the directory in
>   which you started find

Comment: use execdir instead of exec. you don't need to change anything else

Comment: Thank you, I'll try both solution (I can't put in the code the absolute path, but I can figure it out through readlink) EDIT: Sorry wasn't refreshing the page, so I haven't seen your edit!